# sqoop import-all-tables to Hive/HCatalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hcatalog

HDP-2.4.2.0-258 installed using Ambari 2.2.2.0

To import a single table from SQL Server to HCatalog, the following command suffices :

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username  --password  --table SettingAttribute -- --schema Administration  --hcatalog-database FleetManagement --hcatalog-table Administration_SettingAttribute_orc --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile"
```

I'm unsure if this is supported Sqoop, I tried but the files only got imported to HDFS and NOT HCatalog/Hive :

```
sqoop import-all-tables --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --hcatalog-database FleetManagement_Common --create-hcatalog-table --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile" --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;database=FleetManagement' --username --password -- --schema Common
```

I am eager to know if there exists a way to **import all tables from an rdbms schema to Hive/HCatalog in one step** ?